# Jscript .Net and PDF Duo - How to Import DLL?

Tags: .net, javascript

I have an winform application that retrieves some html. I'm trying to convert the html string to a pdf. This is the first time I've tried using an 3rd part library before and I cant seem to get it right.

I'm using /r:pdfduo-net.dll jsc option and my import statement is below:

```
import System;
import System.Text;
import System.Data;
import System.Web;
import System.Web.UI;
import System.Net;
import System.Web.Services;
import System.Net.Security;
import System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
import System.IO;
import System.IO.File;
import System.Windows.Forms;
import System.Threading;
import System.ComponentModel;
import System.Reflection;
import System.Drawing;
import System.Drawing.Graphics;
import System.Collections;
import System.Text.RegularExpressions;
import Accessibility;
import System.Web.Util;
import System.Collections;
import System.Xml;
import DuoDimension;
import DuoDimension.HtmlToPdf;
```

JSC reports that referenced assembly depends on another assembly that is not referenced or cant be found.

Can anyone tell me what I could be missing?

Comment: Does JSC tell you which referenced assembly can't be found? Sometimes that information is hiding in the compilation error or output.

Comment: Nope. All it tells me is this: 
error JS1259: A referenced assembly depends on another assembly that is not referenced or could not be found

Comment: What about RTFM? :) Doesn't PDFDuo tell you which assemblies are needed?

Comment: :) Im unable to locate that anywhere....

Comment: You might try Dependency Walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com to see if it reports anything missing

Answer (score 0):

Although its not really an answer - just want to close this. Form time's sake, I decided to give up on the dll and go command line with HtmlDoc. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but for anyone else with the same problem I would like to mention the following since this plagued me also and an application like Dependency Walker did not help since there is no .exe file to inspect until the compiler is happy so you need to inspect the .js file.

At the time, Dependency Walker was not able to scan .js files and complained:
*Error: At least one file was not a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module.*

The JScript.NET compiler (JSC.exe) will not tell you what dependency it misses (It expects you to know). For instance my very first application I wrote in JScript.NET had:

**import System.Windows.Forms;**

Obviously I needed to draw a form, but this gave me the same error as the OP. In the end adding:

**import System.Drawing;**

fixed it instantly. Due to the lack of help available on the internet for JScript.NET it took me quite a while to work this out.

Another one that fixes this problem sometimes is to add:

**import Accessibility;**

What has helped me immensely is to remove all the code and leave only the imports and maybe an empty class. Then remove the import statements one by one until the compiler stops complaining. The last one you removed is the one that is dependent on another namespace/class. Finding out what it should be comes down to experience and luck. I have always been able to work it out, and I am not even a blue smartie.

In closing I just want to say that JScript.NET is extremely powerful (though half finished), so please keep on using it until Microsoft is forced to support it again due to it's popularity over others currently favored. Within a month I was coding whatever I could dream up using this underrated scripting language.

Hope that helps a little.

dM

Comment: I think I worked out what the OP's problem was: He should add the .dll filename as the import, not the package name inside the .dll. It should also be registered or in the same directory as the calling .exe or it will not find it. i.e. import DuoDimension; & 
import DuoDimension.HtmlToPdf; should become import pdfduo-net. Then call the classes as vars using the full package name+class.

Comment: Here is some further reading for anyone interested: [JScript .NET, Part III](http://www.webreference.com/js/column109/3.html)